# Which opencsv version is Java 6 compatible

Tags: java, csv, compatibility, opencsv

I'm working in a project using Java 6. I need the **opencsv** library but the latest version requires Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through git's history, the requirement for Java 7 was introduced by commit `fd5b507cd4163359a88dc4742b98b321fabae8fd`, which was part of the 4.0 version. Any 3.x version or earlier should work Java 6.

Comment: I thought the same thing,, but that is not the case. I've already tried it and it's not compatible.It throws me the error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/opencsv/CSVWriter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (no puedo cargar clase com.opencsv.CSVWriter)`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest trying [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) so you won't have to use an outdated version of OpenCSV? The latest version is built with Java 6 compatibility and is [way faster](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison). You can use it like this:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //configure the parser
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(); //make it discover the line ending and column separator

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings); //create a parser
List<String[]> parsedRows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/your.csv")); //parse all rows
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)